# Solving a Sum of Complex Exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, singularity

Suppose I have the following equation.

$$e^x+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2 x}=0$$

where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}$.  How do I find all solutions to this equation in the complex plane?  Do I need to use numerical techniques or are there algebraic ways to solve this?  I think the answer to the algebraic is "no" but I was wondering if there was a tried and true method.

Also, what about the variants below

$$e^x+\omega^2 e^{\omega x}+\omega e^{\omega^2 x}=0$$

$$e^x+\omega e^{\omega x}+\omega^2 e^{\omega^2 x}=0$$

Certainly, $x=0$ is a solution to these, but how would i find others?

Comment: Why not?  If you substitute, you get $1+w^2+w=1+w+w^2=0$.  These are just sums of powers of roots of unity?  The first, no, obviously $x=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at the first equation, not the latter two.

Comment: @Lalaloopsy: May I ask why you are interested in this question? I had a similar question a few years ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227161/connection-between-cyclic-group-and-exponential-function

Comment: Related quesition: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323915/product-representation-of-some-exponential-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots are invariant under multiplication by $\omega$.  Here are implicit plots of the real (in blue) and imaginary (in red) parts of $e^x+e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x}$.  The roots are where the red and blue curves intersect: evidently those are points (fairly regularly spaced) along the negative real axis and the rays at angles $\pm 2\pi/3$ from that.

[image]

The first few negative roots are approximately
$$-1.84981279919014, -5.44123335502365, -9.06899753487163, -12.6965955465468, -16.3241942781214, -19.9517930065763$$

Comment: So I think it wold suffice to say that the remaining roots, along the radial angles of $\pm 2\pi/3$ would just be the negative roots multiplied by $\omega$ and $\omega^2$?

Answer (score 4):

your first sum is equal to $${{\rm e}^{x}}+2\,{{\rm e}^{-x/2}}\cos \left( 1/2\,x\sqrt {3} \right) =0$$ i think a numerical method will help here
one solution is given by $$x\approx -1.849812799$$
your second equation is given by $${{\rm e}^{x}}-{{\rm e}^{-x/2}}\cos \left( 1/2\,x\sqrt {3} \right) -
\sqrt {3}{{\rm e}^{-x/2}}\sin \left( 1/2\,x\sqrt {3} \right) 
=0$$
one solution is given by $$x\approx -7.859792867$$