# Product representation of some exponential functions?

Tags: infinite-product, exponential-sum

I was looking at some old questions of mine and stumbled upon this quesiton, which I could not solve:

Define the functions $t_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{3n+k}}{(3n+k)!}}$ for $k=0,1,2$. The functions then satisfy:
$
\begin{pmatrix}\exp(x) \\ \exp(\omega x) \\ \exp(\omega^2 x)\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\1 & \omega^2 & \omega\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}t_0(x) \\ t_1(x) \\ t_2(x)\end{pmatrix}$
where $\omega = \exp(2\pi i / 3)$

and might be defined this way.

As might be known, the matrix in the equation is the character table of the cyclic group $C_3$ and also a Vandermonde matrix. Using this last matrix equation one can prove the following addition theorem:

$\begin{pmatrix}t_0(x+y) \\ t_1(x+y) \\ t_2(x+y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}t_0(x) & t_2(x)  & t_1(x) \\ t_1(x) & t_0(x) & t_2(x)\\ t_2(x) & t_1(x) & t_0(x)\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}t_0(y)\\t_1(y)  \\ t_2(y)\end{pmatrix}$

My question is:

**Is it possible to give a product representation of these functions in terms of the roots of these functions, as is done  for example with the $\sin$-e function?**

Related questions:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227161/connection-between-cyclic-group-and-exponential-function

[Solving a Sum of Complex Exponentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587970/solving-a-sum-of-complex-exponentials)

Comment: These exponential functions don't have any roots, so this might be ... tricky ...

Comment: @EricTowers: No, I do not mean the exponential functions but the $t$ functions.